# Primefaces 5 - Expected identifier, string, or number

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, weblogic

**Background Info:**
App Server: Weblogic 12.1.2
Primefaces 5.0 with JSF 2.1

This morning I encountered the following Javascript error while attempting to access any of the xhtml pages within my application:

```
Expected identifier, string, or number
primefaces.js.xhtml
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:7002/TestApplication/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v5.0
```

No changes were made to my code or my application server between the time I last deployed it the night before and this morning.  I spent several hours doing research today and found quite a bit of information, but nothing I found was able to solve the issue.

I attempted to create a completely new project with 100% default settings.  The problem persists there as well with the new project.

**Caveat**

The error seems to stop manifesting itself when I remove certain components from the page.  For example, I created the following test page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <b>Test Content</b>
    <p:commandButton value="Button"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="Label"/>
    <p:dataTable/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I attempt to view this page, I get the aforementioned errors plus two additional **'PrimeFaces' is undefined** errors.  The page renders and all components MOSTLY seem to work (e.g, in my real application, a data table would populate, a command button would perform an action.), but some components (e.g. selectOneMenu, menuButton and menuitem) do not work.

I do not have any custom Javascript code, and as you can see, I have "h:head" tags.

If I remove the commandButton and dataTable from the sample page above, all errors cease and the page is displayed.  Additionally for good measure, I re-downloaded the PrimeFaces jar to ensure I wasn't using a bad copy (as I had seen in another StackOverflow question).

I'm really at a loss on how to proceed.  Has anyone encountered this before?

As always, thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend pf 5 for production yet, since has some major changes and lots of bugs (we tried to update our app but we ended returning to pf 4), in the other hand, are you using maven?, if not you should check the las stable deploy, since even us could work with buttons and tables in pf 5 (was some other components as list and filters which seems to be broken)

Comment: Did you add primefaces jar file to your build path? It seems it doesn't load the needed js files.

Comment: Just following up.  The Primefaces jar IS added in the build path, and a good portion of the functionality of the Primefaces components work.  Unfortunately, the JavaScript error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue with this was related to IE mostly. If you open Developer Tools on IE and change the compatibility of the browser to IE8 or higher, the error did not show up and the Prime Faces was working more or less.

I am currently in the process of trying to get my prime faces pagers to force the compatibility mode on IE browser via using meta-tags. I may update this answer if I get it working or not.